# Where to put database Model for extensions?

Tags: phpbb

I want to write a small extension that is able to take some informations from the database, based on some user filter preference, and show them on the main page.

I have read: [PHPBB extensions development](https://area51.phpbb.com/docs/dev/3.2.x/extensions/index.html) and took a look at: [ACME DEMO extension](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb-ext-acme-demo) but i didn't find an answer to where the database handling should be placed. Normally this should go into a Model that will handle the data to a Controller, in this case I was not able to figure out where the Model should be placed in to the structure and how it should work.

How should an extension database model should be handled? Where should it sit in to the extension structure?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you would need an event listener.

> PHP event listeners work with core events to inject code into phpBB.
>   Core events are like hooks, and they can be found throughout phpBB’s
>   codebase at key points. They give your extension access to phpBB’s
>   variables and allow you to use and modify them or to inject additional
>   PHP code during phpBB’s execution. -per the [Skeleton Extension
>   Page](https://area51.phpbb.com/docs/dev/3.2.x/extensions/skeleton_extension.html)